# MP3s playing at wrong bitrate on Debian VirtualBox Guest in OS X Host

Tags: mp3, virtual-machine, bitrate

Collection of mp3 files imported to VirtualBox (via binary ftp) from host sound very slow, so assume are playing at wrong bitrate.

Checksums match as per `/usr/bin/openssl md5 *.mp3` (on OS X) and `md5sum *.mp3` on debian.

Even tried moving a file back to OS X host and it plays at the correct rate, so I think the guest (debian) isn't recognizing the bitrate's correctly.

Tried playing the files with three different players: VCL, Movie PLayer and Rhythm Box. Same slow result.

Any recommendations for a next step?

Comment: i think it's the the audio settings either in the guest or host...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. It's working now. I had changed the audio settings of the guest (debian) VM from

```
Host Audio Driver: CoreAudio
Audio Controller: ICH AC97
```

to

```
Host Audio Driver: Null Audio    
Audio Controller: SoundBlaster16
```

At which point there was no audio output.

Went back to CoreAudio / ICH AC97 and sound is fine now.